# Laravel 4 - Creating an artisan command

Tags: php, laravel-4, command, laravel-artisan

This is my first attempt to create an artisan command, which should be responsible for executing another php function. All I did so far is to create the command with: `php artisan command:make PutItemsBackInStock` and created the skeleton for the command. Also, I added the command in `app/start/artisan.php` so Laravel knows about it.

Then in `PutItemsBackInStock` file I declared a private function:

```
private function updateItemQty() { ... }
```

And under the `public function fire()` I tried to call it:

```
$this->updateItemQty();
```

This is probably not the right way to do it, while I got that error:

> [RuntimeException]   Not enough arguments.

Then I removed the blocks for the protected functions `getArguments() and getOptions()` which removed that error but still the function is not firing.

The question is: *How can I get an artisan command to execute another function?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you've not set the arguements correctly. You need to have your command setup something like this:

```
protected $name = 'your:command';

public function fire()
{
    $this->updateItemQty();
}

protected function getArguments()
{
    return [];
}

protected function getOptions()
{
    return [];
}

private function updateItemQty() { ... }
```